# Question and Answer software for use during presentations

Tags: software-rec, presentations

I'm looking for software that will allow an audience to collectively formulate and vote-up questions during a presentation which can be relayed back to the speaker either during or after the talk. The goal would be to structure and prioritize questions from a large audience to the speaker, such as during conferences, by members of the audience using laptops and possibly smartphones.

I vaguely remember reading about a tool like this a few years ago that Google employed during their Tech Talks. If I'm not mistaken they had this running on Google App Engine. However I can't remember where I read about this, nor can I find any reference to it now.

Can anyone recommend such a tool that will allow for quick interaction from an audience with the ability to upvote questions?

Comment: Is the qa tag for quality assurance or tools that support question&answer sessions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in Software recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called [Google Moderator](http://moderator.appspot.com/).

<sub>I know, it's a web app, but the OP asked for it!</sub>

[image]

Also see the guide on [how Google Moderator works](https://sites.google.com/site/moderatorhelpcenter/getting-started/guide):

> Google Moderator allows you to create a series about anything that you are interested in discussing and open it up for people to submit questions, ideas, or suggestions. These are called submissions.
>
> [...]
>
> If you see a question that's been submitted, you can vote to recommend that it's asked. To do so, simply click the checkmark button. You can also click the X button if you'd like to vote against an existing question. When you mouse over the bars, you'll see the number of votes that have already been submitted.